# long polling ajax and php how do I make this code long polling?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

I want once my long polling ajax on network chrome keep pending instead of calling every x seconds ., I tried changing by timeout , but nothing worked. I also want to keep updated my data , but without calling it every x seconds. my function just a prototype , but want to tests everything is okay , but when I see chrome network is calling every 2s how can I change it to call only when data is changed?

polling

```
 var poll = function function_name() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL_GET_NOTIFICATIONS,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.user-counter').text(data.notifications);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        // body...
                    }
                });
            };

            poll();

            setInterval(function () {
                poll()
            }, 2000);
        });
```

server notifications

```
public function FunctionName(){
    $this->json(array('notifications' => 200));
}
```

Comment: You remove the trigger firing every 2 seconds and instead reexecute the call every time the previous call returned, either successful or not. That way it is completely up to the server to respond whenever it seems fit. Either because there is new data or later, which might lead to a timeout. In both cases the client will establish the next connection right away which is exactly what you want.

Comment: in code how will it be?